# how make a list an element of all rows of a df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame and I have a list. How I can make a new column in my df and have the list in all rows?

`list_skill=[A,B,C,D]`

df

```
  col     new_list
  pdf     [A,B,C,D]
  dog     [A,B,C,D]
  dev     [A,B,C,D]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `apply()` method:-

```
df['new_list']=df['col'].apply(lambda x:list_skill)
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your expected output:-

```
    col     new_list
0   pdf     [A, B, C, D]
1   dog     [A, B, C, D]
2   dev     [A, B, C, D]
```

Comment: I wanna add it to whole data set not just `col`

Comment: just use this code it will added to whole dataset...not just in `col`

Answer (score 0):

#### `np.tile`

```
df['new_list'] = np.tile(list_skill, (len(df), 1)).tolist()
```

---

```
   col      new_list
0  pdf  [A, B, C, D]
1  dog  [A, B, C, D]
2  dev  [A, B, C, D]
```

Answer (score -1):

import  pandas  as pd

json = []

df = pd.DataFrame(json)

df['test1'] = df['test2'] = df['test3'] = [['A','B','C','D'],['A','B','C','D'],
['A','B','C','D']]

print(df)